# Why is $f_{s}(0)=0$ for $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2}$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Using the fact that, 
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h},$$
I was able to prove that if $f \colon (a,b)\to\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $x\in (a,b)$, then the limit $$f_s(x)\triangleq\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h},$$
exists. My book then says that the converse does not hold, and I'm given $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ as a counter-example, with $f_s(0)=0$; however, I get $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}-\frac{1}{(x-h)^2}}{2h}=-\frac{2}{x^3},$$ which is undefined at $x=0$. I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I am misunderstanding. Thank you in advance.

---

Here is my algebra for the limit:

> $\begin{alignat*}{2}
>      \lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}-\frac{1}{(x-h)^2}}{2h}&=\frac{1}{2}\ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{(x+h)^2}-\frac{1}{(x-h)^2}}{h}\\
>      &=\frac{1}{2}\ \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{-\frac{4hx}{(x-h)^2(h+x)^2}}{\frac{h(h-x)^2}{(x-h)^2}}\\
>      &=\frac{1}{2}\ \lim_{h\to 0}-\frac{4x}{(h-x)^2(h+x)^2}\\
>      &=-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{4x}{(0-x)^2(0+x)^2}=-\frac{2}{x^3}\\
> \end{alignat*}$

Comment: I do not see what $s$ is...

Comment: @Gibbs the first limit, by definition.

Comment: I think that in your calculation you wrote somewhere something like:
$$(x+h)^2=x^2 \left(1+\frac{h}{x} \right)^2$$
which is illegal for $x=0$.

Comment: Your error is that to get that limit you divided by $x$ in your computation to simplify a fraction. See Delta-u answer.

Comment: @Delta-u I have edited my answer to include my algebra. What do you think?

Comment: In your algebra you take the limit $h \to 0$ for $x \neq 0$ then $x \to 0$.
But it is dangerous to invert limits as this example show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x=0$ you have:
$$f(x+h)=f(0+h)=\frac{1}{h^2}$$
$$f(x+h)=f(0-h)=\frac{1}{h^2}$$
so, $\forall h \neq 0$:
$$\frac{f(0+h)-f(0-h)}{2h}=0$$
and in particular:
$$f_s(0)=0$$

Comment: Is it a matter of substituting x=0 before solving the limit?

Comment: Yes exactly :-).